# How to change object of an observable in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an observable in witch I get data from server and I need on init to filtre this data and use it in project. How we can do this in angular ?

```
//get data from server
this.sites = _httpClient.get<IModel[]>('api/mysites');
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
   //there I show data from server
   this.sites.subscribe(x=> console.log('first console', x));
   
   //and there I need to have filtred data 
   this.sites.subscribe(x=> console.log('second console', x));

}
```

Comment: this.sites.pipe(filter(x => x )).subscribe(x => x)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter the data, your best bet would be to use the filter pipe:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sites
   .pipe(filter(x => // filter data here))
   .subscribe(x=> console.log('first console', x));

  // 'first console' will print your filtered data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Use Pipes to transform your data once you get the value from the Server 
https://angular.io/guide/pipes Refer this for more information on transforming data
```

```html
        this.sites = _httpClient.get<IModel[]>('api/mysites').pipe(
         
    );

      ngOnInit(): void {
       //there I show data from server
       this.sites.subscribe(x=> console.log('first console', x));
       
       //and there I need to have filtred data 
       this.sites.subscribe(x=> console.log('second console', x));

    }
```